# Controlling placement of "set" of figures in a two-column document

Tags: floats, positioning, ieee-style

I have 8-figures that need to come in sequence (no text/section in between) in a two-column IEEEtran documentclass (all fit in 1.5 pages if no text in between).

How can I control the set of figures placement '[place]' effectually in order to control them all with one command (to be all placed next to each other) and not to have any text breaking in between? Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of only one figure here (another 7-figs to be added):

```
documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tp]
\begin{center}
{\resizebox{0.52\textwidth}{0.21\textwidth}{{\includegraphics*{Fig_11.eps}}}
\midskip \footnotesize{\verb+      +(a)}\vspace{-0.6 cm}
\label{fig:Fig_11}
\end{center}}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\centering` not `\begin{center}` in figures but just putting 8 consecutive `\begin{figure}[p]..\end[figure]` should work, (possibly followed by `\clearpage` also it's much easier to use `graphicx` and `\includegraphics[width=.52\textwidth]{Fig_11}`

Answer (score 1):

just a sequence of floats should work, but it's better to use `graophicx` syntax, especially as you are loading that package, so no need to wrap the image in `\resizebox`. Also whether using `\resizebox` or the built in scaling, best not to scale in both directions as it will distort the image.  `figure` already adds space, so use `\centering` not `\begin{center}`. `\label` needs a `\caption` or it will refer to the surrounding section, not this figure, and the syntax for a size change is `{\footnotesize zzz}` not `\footnotesize{zzz}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, multirow}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{ (a)\label{fig:Fig_11}}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir, I learnt some new stuff from your explanation on `centering` for tables. However, I had already made the 8 working figures in my text and I did not have any issue in generating them. issue is that: if text comes after/before the "set" of figures and one doesn't command the set unifiedly, they will split and text will come in between. maybe creating some blind texts using `\lipsum` in your code above can give some insight to what I need to solve (also I don't want all the figures in one page, 1.5 page is what it should be set for to see how text can affect it).